# Problems with char(4) FK, entity framework

Tags: entity-framework

I'm having a char(4) FK reltionship, and it gives me lots of errors when I use that in my designer.

I have a relation between tables:   BookingObjects 1:* IntervalEntities, and it is a char(4) PK in the IntervalEntities table.

Error   9   Error 3007: Problem in Mapping Fragments starting at lines 813, 1037: Non-Primary-Key column(s) [IntervalEntityID] are being mapped in both fragments to different conceptual side properties - data inconsistency is possible because the corresponding conceptual side properties can be independently modified.

and:

Error   10  Error 3012: Problem in Mapping Fragments starting at lines 813, 1037: Data loss is possible in BookingObjects.IntervalEntityID.
An Entity with Key (PK) will not round-trip when:
  (PK does NOT play Role 'BookingObject' in AssociationSet 'FK_BookingObjects_IntervalEntities' AND PK is in 'BookingObjects' EntitySet)

What can be wrong?

/M

Comment: post a screenshot of your relevant EF diagram and your database structure with the relationships, etc.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

http://csentities.wordpress.com/2009/10/07/adding-filter-to-the-dynamic-data-application-page-blog-post-5/

seems to have solved it, atleast I dont get errors when I build solution